# Why do I get "Illegal characters in path" while using XmlDiff to compare 2 xml files?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem trying to compare 2 xml files with the XmlDiff library from Microsoft.

I am using an overloaded function which passes 2 xmls as strings :

```
xmldiff = new XmlDiff(XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreChildOrder | XmlDiffOptions.IgnorePrefixes | XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreNamespaces);
bool identical = xmldiff.Compare(first, last, false);
```

where `first` and `last` look more or less like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <description>two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <description>light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

And I get this error

[image]

**EDIT:**

OK, I think that was my issue - I passed whole content of the file instead of just its path or URL(as in the documentation). So now I have another problem - how can I use this overload -  `public Boolean Compare(XmlReader, XmlReader)` or this `public Boolean Compare(XmlNode, XmlNode)` when I have the file contents in a string ?

Comment: I would check if xmldiff.Compare() expects a path to an XML file or the actual XML as a string...

Comment: OK, I think that was my issue - I passed whole content of the file instead of just its path or URL(as in the documentation). So now I have another problem - how can I use this overload -  public Boolean Compare(XmlReader, XmlReader) or this public Boolean Compare(XmlNode, XmlNode) when I have the file contents in a string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to pass the file path to `Compare`, not the xml string.

Comment: I want to pass the xml contents not the path as required ( take a look at my edit)

Answer (score 0):

What type is first and last? Are they file paths? Or strings?
I notice the encoding on your XML string is using a code page: encoding="ISO-8859-1"
Is the other  XML 'thing' using the same encoding?

If 'first' and 'last' are file paths: Perhaps it's your path of the files you are passing to the files? I encountered that once when parsing some files. I had an extra space in the filename.
It didn't help I was programming in an IDE with small font, and I need new glasses and I was sitting 3 feet away from the monitor. 
That made it a bugger to see the tiny tiny space in the filename.

Comment: As I wrote: 'they look like this' - they are strings, contents of the files. All the files contents are the same, only there are two integers in which they differ so that I would be able to test the XmlDiff.